# Go: how to convert unsafe.Pointer into pointer to array with unknown length?

Tags: arrays, go, mmap

I am trying to write a Go program which uses `mmap` to map a very large file containing `float32` values into memory.  Here is my attempt (inspired by a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203526/mapping-an-array-to-a-file-via-mmap-in-go), error handling omitted for brevity):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fileName := "test.dat"
    info, _ := os.Stat(fileName)
    fileSize := info.Size()
    n := int(fileSize / 4)

    mapFile, _ := os.Open(fileName)
    defer mapFile.Close()
    mmap, _ := syscall.Mmap(int(mapFile.Fd()), 0, int(fileSize),
        syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
    defer syscall.Munmap(mmap)
    mapArray := (*[n]float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap[0]))

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Println(mapArray[i])
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
./main.go:21: non-constant array bound n
```

Since `n` is determined by the length of the file (not known at compile time), I cannot replace `n` with a constant value in the cast.  How do I convert `mmap` into an array (or slice) of `float32` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first convert to an array of a type with a static length that can fit your data, then slice that array to the correct length and capacity.

```
mapSlice := (*[1 << 30]float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap[0]))[:n:n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't get a pointer to an *array* in your case. This is because `n` is not a constant value (i.e. it's determined at runtime with `fileSize/4`). (Note If `fileSize` were constant, you could get an array.)

There are safe and unsafe alternatives though.

The safe, or some might call the "right" way -- this requires a copy, but you have control over the endianness. Here's an example:

```
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "bytes"
    "unsafe" // optional
)

const SIZE_FLOAT32 = unsafe.Sizeof(float32(0)) // or 4

bufRdr := bytes.NewReader(mmap)
mapSlice := make([]float32, len(mmap)/SIZE_FLOAT32) // = fileSize/4
err := binary.Read(bufRdr, binary.LittleEndian, mapSlice) // could pass &mapSlice instead of mapSlice: same result.
// mapSlice now can be used like the mapArray you wanted.
```

There are a couple ways to do this unsafely, but with Go 1.17 it's pretty simple.

```
mapSlice := unsafe.Slice((*float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap[0])), len(mmap)/SIZE_FLOAT32)
```

You could also use `reflect.SliceHeader`. There are lots of nuances to be careful of here to prevent garbage collector issues:

```
var mapSlice []float32 // mapSlice := []float32{} also works (important thing is that len and cap are 0)

// newSh and oldSh are here for readability (i.e. inlining these variables is ok, but makes things less readable IMO)
newSh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&mapSlice))
oldSh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap))

// Note: order of assigning Data, Cap, Len is important (due to GC)
newSh.Data = oldSh.Data
newSh.Cap = oldSh.Cap/SIZE_FLOAT32
newSh.Len = oldSh.Len/SIZE_FLOAT32

runtime.KeepAlive(mmap) // ensure `mmap` is not freed up until this point.
```

The final `unsafe` way I can think of is given in @JimB's answer -- cast an `mmap`'s `Data` to an `unsafe.Pointer`, then cast that to an arbitrarily large pointer to array, and then finally slice that array specifying to desired size and capacity.